# ActiveMQ persistent store is full and consumer is blocked

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm doing a test to see how the flow control behaves. I created a fast producer and slow consumers and set my destination queue policy highwater mark to 60 percent..

the queue did reach 60% so messages now went to the store, now the store is full and blocking as expected..

But now i cannot get my consumer to connect and pull from the queue.. Seem that blocking is also blocking the consumer from getting in to start pulling from the queue..

Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: With my test I have a consumer thread and a producer thread. Each doing there thing with a deliberate delay with the consumer.. The consumer was in a while loop with a timer, so i was creating a new consumer with each iteration. When the queue was blocked I could no longer create a consumer.. When I refactored and created a single consumer I was then able to receive from the queue..So, my test implementation was throwing me off..

Answer (score 0):

The consumer should not be blocked by flow-control. Otherwise messages could not be consumed to free up space on the broker for producers to send additional messages.

Answer (score 0):

So this issues surfaced when I was using a on demand jms service. The service will queue or dequeue via a REST services. The consumers are created on demand.. If the broker is being blocked as im my case being out of resource, then you cannot create a new consumer.

I've since modified the jms service to use a consumer pool(implemented a object pool pattern). The consumer pool is initialized when the application starts and this resolved the blocking issue

Comment: For what it's worth your original question mentions nothing about this intermediary REST layer which was actually causing the problem. It was only asking about the broker.